# Validation doesn't work in "sexy" style

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

It seems that Rails doens't let me pass in more than one parameter when using this validation syntax. It always has a syntax method for an unexpected comma after the first argument.

```
class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
geocoded_by :location
after_validation :geocode
has_many :image_attachments
validates_associated :image_attachments

accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_attachments

validates :location, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
validates :price, :presence => true
                ,:format => { with: /^[0-9]+$/, message: 'must be a number' }


validates :longitude, presence: true


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad formatting (and very "unsexy") to have the comma at the beginning of the next line.

Better to do...

```
validates :price, :presence => true,
                  :format => { with: /^[0-9]+$/, message: 'must be a number' }
```

...which should work fine.

A more consistent style is to use the Ruby 1.9 convention for key/value when key is a symbol.

```
validates :price, presence: true,
                  format: { with: /^[0-9]+$/, message: 'must be a number' }
```

Comment: tnx this helped. Didn't know that this mattered.

Comment: It matters because Ruby uses record-separator (carriage return) to separate statements. If it hits a record-separator and the command looks complete, then it thinks it's complete. Otherwise the ruby parser would have to continually be scanning the next line to see if it's relevant to the current command, which would be inefficient.  The comma before the CR acts like a flag to tell ruby there's more coming.